# get a List element from jsp in the servlet

Tags: jquery, jsp, post, servlets, jakarta-ee

i am a beginner building a simple jsp that displays in a table the content of a list ( a collection) and for every line in my table there is a button as shown below :
[the jsp page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pv6qD.png)

i wanna pass the id of the product as a parameter  to the servlet when clicking on its button so i tried with jquery ; here what it looks like :
[the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwJ1z.png)

the servlet :
[the servlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7y54.png)
however it's not working , can anyone explain to me where is the mistake ? or if there is a better way to do it , i'll be so thankful .

Comment: Well the getParameter is not returning anything , i thought the problem is in getting the parent id value so i replaced it by a simple string (in the script : selectedOne:'hello' ) but even with that i am not getting a result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just buttons. Clicking will not have any effect.

- Replace buttons with
  `<input type="submit" ...>`
- Or add JavaScript that submits this form:
  `onclick="document.getElementById('your form ID').submit();"`